# Adding a weighted least squares trendline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, weighted, trendline

I am preparing a plot using ggplot2, and I want to add a trendline that is based on a weighted least squares estimation.

In base graphics this can be done by sending a WLS model to `abline`:

```
mod0 <- lm(ds$dMNP~ds$MNP)
mod1 <- lm(ds$dMNP~ds$MNP, weights = ds$Asset)

symbols(ds$dMNP~ds$MNP, circles=ds$r, inches=0.35)
#abline(mod0)
abline(mod1)
```

in ggplot2 I set the argument `weight` in `geom_smooth` but nothing changes:

```
ggplot(ds, aes(x=MNP, y=dMNP, size=Asset) + 
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", weight="Asset", color="black", show.legend = FALSE)
```

this gives me the same plot as

```
ggplot(ds, aes(x=MNP, y=dMNP, size=Asset) + 
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color="black", show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you adjust this to a built-in data set for reproducibility?

Comment: You can put `weight` in the `aes` and `geom_smooth` will use it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm late, but for posterity and clarity, here is the full solution:

```
ggplot(ds, aes(x = MNP, y = dMNP, size = Asset)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", mapping = aes(weight = Asset), 
              color = "black", show.legend = FALSE)
```

Don't put the weight name in quotes.

Comment: I get the following error message `The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: weight, size
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into
  a factor?`

Comment: But the curve obtained is still weighted, which is good

Comment: This would get rid of the error message: ggplot(ds, aes(x = MNP, y = dMNP)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21,aes(size = Asset)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", mapping = aes(weight = Asset), 
              color = "black", show.legend = FALSE)

Comment: The weight warning with some geoms has been fixed in recent versions of ggplot2.