# Error in stats::model.frame...: object not found when specifying weights inside geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, smoothing, weighted

The example code is the following (it may have no sense statistically, but the problem is the `object not found`). While next works:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = vs, y = mpg)) + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

Next does not:

```
> mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = vs, y = mpg)) + geom_smooth(method=lm(weights = cyl))
Error in stats::model.frame(weights = cyl, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  object 'cyl' not found
```

Why this error? What can I do to solve it?

I also tried

```
> mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = vs, y = mpg)) + geom_smooth(method=lm(weights = "cyl"))
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  argument is not a valid model
```

and other variants with `""`, with more info inside `lm`, etc., but without success.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this... `geom_smooth(aes(weight = cyl), method = "lm")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a weighted least squares trendline in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507098/adding-a-weighted-least-squares-trendline-in-ggplot2)

Comment: As pointed out by @AndrewGustar, [specify weights in the `weight` aesthetic](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XgFkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=geom_smooth+with+weights&source=bl&ots=so3-bM8-bS&sig=ACfU3U39iFlL1E196khn6Ta4gpRTvVn18A&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqqPLpvpHlAhU7DWMBHXtlB5AQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=geom_smooth%20with%20weights&f=false)

Comment: This is similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240350/custom-lm-formula-in-geom-smooth

Comment: I had seen already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507098/adding-a-weighted-least-squares-trendline-in-ggplot2 and I felt like it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = vs, y = mpg)) +  
   stat_smooth(method="lm", aes(weight= cyl))
```

This will generate a graph, but I am not sure if it is what you after. `weight` here may not different from the `weights` you wanted to use.