# How to add certain circles on a regression line plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

[image]

1. The line on the picture is a weighted least squares trendline,and I plan to use ggplot to draw it.
2. The ordinate of the center of a circle is the Y-axis value("HR for CHD……");

We can see ten different cirlces in the picture because there are ten different "HR" value, and every set of data points have the same Y value（a total of 10 sets of data points）.

【Sorry there was a mistake I just made! Maybe the abscissa of the circle centre is the average of X value of a set of data points? 】

3.The size of the circle depends on the sample size.

```
df <- data.frame(y=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8),
                 x=c(48, 78, 72, 70, 66, 92, 93, 75, 75, 80, 95, 97, 90, 96, 99, 99))
```

Just use these data for test.I have known how to draw a weighted least squares trendline in ggplot, but how can I add 8 circles( there are 8 different "y" value in the test data) .

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick OK. I edit it.

Comment: Where is the variable that includes the sample size?

Comment: @mikebader Uh……I don't know what to do next. Do I need to create a new data frame including count results? Just like
```
countresult <- data.frame(y=c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 count=c(2,3,1,4,2,2,1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second plot to the original plot.

Suppose that you had a third variable named `samp`. You would use `geom_point` and set the `size` aesthetic to equal the sample size.

I'm not exactly sure how you will enter the data predicted by WLS, but to add the circles you would add:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(y=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8),
                 x=c(48, 78, 72, 70, 66, 92, 93, 75, 75, 80, 95, 97, 90, 96, 99, 99)
)

df <- df %>%
    group_by(y) %>%
    add_count() %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), mean))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = n)) +
    geom_point(shape = 21) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", mapping = aes(weight = n),
                color = "red")
```

Comment: But the structue of data frame of WLS PLOT is different from the sample size.（Data to predicted by WLS is longitudinal data) . Maybe we can't add a second plot to the original code when the two plots don‘t share the same data frame?

I plan to refer to this case to draw a WLS PLOT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507098/adding-a-weighted-least-squares-trendline-in-ggplot2

Comment: It would help a lot if you can provide an example of your data by, for example, using the `dput()` command. I also do not understand how the WLS plot will be longitudinal given what you have provided in your question.

Comment: Can this case be work?Just like the longitudinal data in this case https://www.statology.org/weighted-least-squares-in-r/
I refer to its data example  but I switched the values of x and y.  The case doesn't use ggplot, but I think I can  deal with it.

Comment: The circle's size only depends on the sample size of same Y-axis values. It doesn't matter whether the X-axis values are the same or not. We only need to count how many Y values are identical.

Comment: @tumidou, so you are saying that you want the circle at y=2 to be 1.5 times larger than the circle at y=1 and the circle at y=4 to be 2 times larger than the circle at y=1?

Comment: Yes! The size of the circle depends only on the sample size of Y values.

Comment: Your data do not match the example plot. That plot contains three variables: an independent variable (Difference in Lp(a) nmol/L), a dependent variable (HR for CHD), and a sample size variable (the size of the circles). Given what you said, however, I have created a new variable, `n`, that contains the count of each `y`, but it produces multiple points for each y-value, unlike the plot.

Comment: You're right, so I guest the X-axis value of the circle centre is the average  of all x values which map to the same y.
For example, three points:  (72,2)  (70,2) (66,2)   generate the circle centre (average(72,70,66),2)= (67.33,2).

Comment: I added the command `summarise(across(everything(), mean))` to accomplish that.